# Get an environment variable into a WiX property

Tags: wix, environment

Is there a way to get an environment variable into a WiX property?

I'm trying to get the `USERPROFILE` with:

```
Property Id="UserFolder"  Value="$(env.USERPROFILE)\EdwardsApp\MyFolder"
```

But this only picks up the `USERPROFILE` of the build machine where the installer is built.

I want it to use the `USERPROFILE` of the machine where the app is being installed.

Comment: Using $(env.USERPROFILE) would bring you the value of UserProfile on your build machine while you would be building your Wix installer. Some good solutions are already replied.

Comment: In addition to Farrukh's comment: The `$(env...)` syntax comes from the [WiX Preprocessor](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make use of Environment variables during installation but this requires using a custom action. You will need to set the `UserFolder` property with a [`Type 51 Custom Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368237%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) as opposed to setting the property during the build. The [%ENVVARNAME] format is used to make use of an environment variable, but the name of the environment variable is case-sensitive.

A WiX example of a custom action that sets a property:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetUserFolder" Property="UserFolder" Value="[%USERPROFILE]EdwardsApp\MyFolder" />
```

You can read more on Custom Actions in WiX here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/21/from-msi-to-wix-part-5-custom-actions.aspx

Comment: USERPROFILE doesn't have a trailing backslash, so shouldn't it be:
Value="[%USERPROFILE]\EdwardsApp\MyFolder"

Comment: I'm trying to use the ProgramFiles(x86) environment variable yet I can't seem to figure out how to escape the parenthesis.  I always get ICE03: Invalid format string.  Anyone know how to use this environment variable?

Answer (score 21):

Alternative is to use [SetProperty element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_setproperty.htm) - it will effectively create type 51 custom Action. It is simpler than using Custom Action as you don't need to separately specify the schedule for it - everything is done in one element. In my example below, I set the property only if its empty, i.e. was not passed from the command line.

Example:

```
<SetProperty Id="PROP_MYSOME"
             Before="InstallInitialize" 
             Sequence="execute"
             Value="[%USERDOMAIN]">
    <![CDATA[NOT Installed AND PROP_MYSOME=""]]>
</SetProperty>
```

Answer (score 9):

Since I can't add a comment yet, with regard to @demp's answer, I had to do this to get the condition to evaluate sometime during initialization so that the value could be displayed in a UI dialog:

```
<SetProperty Id="MY_PROPERTY"
             Value="[%USERDOMAIN]" 
             After="LaunchConditions"
             Sequence="first"  />
```

I *believe* that `Before="InstallInitialize"` happens just before the installation itself proceeds (i.e. copying files and whatnot) and **not** during the initialization phase of the installer itself.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I'm looking to get the USERPROFILE environment variable of the target machine to install all the files there. I achieved that like:

```
<Property Id="HOME_FOLDER" >
  <DirectorySearch Id="userProfileSearch" Depth="0" Path="[%USERPROFILE]" />
</Property>
```

Then all the files went where i wanted them to go.