# How can I check the existence of an environment variable?

Tags: wix, environment-variables, conditional-compilation

The [documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/preprocessor.htm) for `if`/`ifdef` is slightly confusing. For `<?if [expression] ?>`, it states:

> - Variables can be used to check for existence
>     ...
> - If the variable doesn't exist, evaluation will fail and an error will be raised.

It turns out if you just go: `<?if $(env.MY_VAR) ?>` and `MY_VAR` is not defined, compilation will fail. How do I check for existence?

Ordinarily, this is where one would use an `ifdef`, but these work strangely in Wix too. Instead of using `$(var.Variable)` syntax, they use `<?ifdef Variable?>`, meaning *environment* variables can't be checked this way.

What do I need to do to get the equivalent of normal c pre-processor:

```
#ifdef MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE
```

in Wix?

Comment: Note: `<?ifdef MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE ?>` does not work on its own.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The correct way to reference environment variables in `ifdef` sections is:

```
<?ifdef env.MY_VAR?>
  ...
<?endif?>
```

This works as expected.

Comment: @Cymon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459998/get-an-environment-variable-into-a-wix-property?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Thanks, man, your question and your answer just saved me! I understand that WiX toolset source is open, but the documentation has its merits too.

Answer (score 5):

```
<Condition Message="Missing Environment Variable Message Goes Here"><![CDATA[%envvargoeshere]]></Condition>
```

Put the above element in the Package element of the wxs file.
The installation will fail at runtime (install time) with a nice message if the environment variable does not exist.