# WiX: Use [ComputerName] with property in Transforms.xml

Tags: variables, wix, built-in, computer-name

I need to use the built-in variable [ComputerName] in a property in a Transforms.xml WiX file.

What I'm doing:  `<Property Id="MYCOMPUTERNAME" VALUE="[ComputerName]" />`

What shows up is: "[ComputerName]"

That's not what I want.

I want the real computer name made available to the Property "MYCOMPUTERNAME".

Has anyone tried this successfully and how?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

WiX has a way to access environment variables. Check out the tutorial:

http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/expression-syntax

I think the syntax you would use is this, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I appreciate the link, but it didn't work.  I tried setting the value to "$(env.ComputerName)" and to "%COMPUTERNAME".  In either case, I get a literal value ($(env.ComputerName) or %COMPUTERNAME) placed in the variable.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459998/get-an-environment-variable-into-a-wix-property) is what you want. You need to use the <SetProperty/> element. [Here's] (http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_setproperty.htm) the documentation reference.

Comment: Thank you, but I get an **"MsiTransform -- FAILED"** error when making use of `<SetProperty/>` in the Transforms.xml file.  I used `Sequence="execute"` and `Before="InstallInitialization"` inside the tag.  When I remove the `<SetProperty/>` tag, it compiles well.