# WIX check if file exists while installing

Tags: wix

I'm having a problem with my WIX installer. I want to check if a special file exists and if, it should be installed, else not. So currently I'm doing a file search:

```
<Property Id="FileExists">
  <DirectorySearch Id="CheckFileDir" Path="..." Depth="0">
    <FileSearch Id="CheckFile" Name="Some.dll"/>
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
```

And set the feature level to null if it does not exist:

```
<Feature Id="Feature_1" Title="Feature_1" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id="ComponentId"/>
  <Condition Level="0">NOT FileExists</Condition>
</Feature>
```

But how must my component look like?

```
<Component Id="ComponentID" Directory="Direc" KeyPath="yes" Guid="GUID_FD6FB7A51317" >
  <File Id="FileId" Name="file.dll" Source="$(var.accessPath)access.dll" Vital="no"/>
</Component>
```

If I do so I get the error message that the file "$(var.accessPath)access.dll" could not be found.

Edit 1: accessPath is defined as:

```
<?define accessPath="%Variable%\bin\"?>
```

I'm very grateful for every help!

Hendrik

Comment: How is $(var.SimuarteaccessPath) defined?

Comment: <?define SimuarteaccessPath="%PUMA%\COBRA\bin\"?>

Comment: %PUMA% is your environment variable? If yes it should be defined `<?define SimuarteaccessPath="$(env.PUMA)\COBRA\bin\"?>`

Comment: Yes it's an environment variable, but only on a few systems the installation should be installed on.

Comment: You are mixing up WiX and Windows Installer concepts. `<?` and `$(` are WiX preprocessor things. Properties `[NAME]` is a Windows Installer thing. WiX has no part in the installation itself; it only builds the MSI (except if you use a custom action provided by WiX). [Sorry no time for a full answer.]

Comment: Thanks, now I understood where my problem is. So I need a custom action to solve this.

Comment: Only for interest: WiX needs the locations of all the files to compile? The vital attribute is only therfor that something went wrong while installing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get an environment variable into a WIX property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459998/get-an-environment-variable-into-a-wix-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tom Blodget mentioned in the comments I mixed up WiX and Windows Installer concepts.

If you want to check if a file exists during an installation, you have to do it with Custom Actions.